# How can I run a React app using Largon development environment

Tags: php, reactjs, apache, laragon

I have a php based backend and a React based front end.
I am following this tutorial https://whilenext.com/javascript/handling-react-routes-with-apache-and-expressjs, but I cannot see the urls changing properly:
on every click on link to a different "page" in this SPA is set on the localhost domain: for instance: "localhost\login" but it should be "localhost\mysite\login".
Also, the http requests to the backend php code are not seem to be executed. The point where I got stuck is with runing the
"a2enmod rewrite" comand on the apache server- as in the tutorial. I can't seem to understand how Laragon controls everything.
Your explanation on how to proceed is most welcome!